# Perl DBD fetchrow_array error:

Tags: mysql, perl

I got some strange error when reading MySQL, my code is something like this:

```
my $sql = <<"sqleof";
select t1.name t1_name, t2.name t2_name from t2
    inner join t1 using(Id)
    where t2.Id in (select Id from t3 where t3Id='$id') 
sqleof
#here $dbh had connected correctly and done some query before this; $sql can execute pretty well on MySQL command line and return me some records.
my $execute = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$execute->execute or die "Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
my @client = $execute->fetchrow_array() or die "Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
#here I got error saying: DBD::ODBC::st fetchrow_array failed:     Unable to fetch information about the error
```

What's the problem?

Hi, all, sorry to bother you. I had found the reason. It's a low level miss, as I had used multiple $dbh and I make a mistake of the execute name.

```
    my $execute_A = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$execute_A->execute or die "Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
my @client = $execute_B->fetchrow_array()  #$execute_B here when I copied lines and modified.
```

Your helps are of much importance to me. Thank you all.

Comment: You've tagged `mysql` and error suggests you're using it with ODBC which is very unusual setup.

Comment: I use Windows ODBC Data Source administrator created DSN and the DSN use a MySQL ODBC connector to connect the remote database. Your comments is valuable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
my @client = $execute->fetchrow_array() or die "Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

with

```
my @client = $execute->fetchrow_array();
```

You're fetching empty array and this is not suitable for error checking as `..or die ..` suggests.

`.. or die ..` makes sense only for `prepare` and `execute` methods.

---

Side note, you're also lacking proper error checking:

```
my $execute = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbh->errstr; # not $DBI::errstr
$execute->execute or die $execute->errstr;             # not $DBI::errstr
```

also, use **sql placeholders** to prevent [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Not *exactly* true that you shouldn't do error checking for `fetch` methods (but you're right about not using `or die`). From the [DBI docs](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.630/DBI.pm#fetchrow_array): *"If there are no more rows or if an error occurs, then fetchrow_array returns an empty list. You should check $sth->err **afterwards** (or use the RaiseError attribute) to discover if the empty list returned was due to an error."* (emphasis mine)

Comment: @ysth but makes much less sense when using multiple DBI instances

Comment: I copied and run the $sql on command line and can return me 5 records. So I didn't know why I'm fetching the empty array.

Comment: the $sth->err returns "1" and the $DBI::errstr returns Unable to fetch information about the error. Seems no more useful message for me.

Comment: @anaconda_wly does query returns something on command line? Try `$dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;` for automated error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the variable $id in your sql query to ? and then pass the variable through execute. Like $execute->execute($id)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the execute causes your mysql server to crash. This is the only reason i can think of that would explain the "unable to fetch information about the error". If you're using safe_mysqld, you might not even notice since it gets restarted automatically.

If that is on a web site, and you get this error once in a while, then someone is trying to hack you by putting stuff like `3' or 'a'='a` in your form (try what happens if you replace id with this string in your question). If they get the format wrong, the server might try to execute anything. To prevent this kind of SQL Injection attack, rewrite your query to

```
my $sql = <<"sqleof";
select t1.name t1_name, t2.name t2_name from t2
    inner join t1 using(Id)
    where t2.Id in (select Id from t3 where t3Id=?) 
sqleof
```

and call `$execute->execute($id)`.